# Storm SQS messages not getting acked

Tags: apache-storm, amazon-sqs

I have a topology with 1 spout reading from 2 SQS queues and 5 bolts. After processing when i try to ack from second bolt it is not getting acked.

I'm running it in reliable mode and trying to ack in the last bolt. I get this message as if the messages are getting acked. But it is not getting deleted from the queue and the overwritten `ack()` methods are not getting called. It looks like it calls the default ack method in `backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector` instead of the overridden method in my spout.

```
8240 [Thread-24-conversionBolt] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: conversionBolt__ack_ack [-7578372739434961741 -8189877254603774958]
```

I have anchored message ID to the tuple in my SQS queue spout and emitting to first bolt.

```
collector.emit(getStreamId(message), new Values(jsonObj.toString()), message.getReceiptHandle());
```

I have ack() and fail() methods overridden in my queue `spout.Default Visibility Timeout` has been set to 30 seconds

Code snippet from my topology:

```java
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("firstQueueSpout",
                new SqsQueueSpout(StormConfigurations.getQueueURL()
                        + StormConfigurations.getFirstQueueName(), true),
                StormConfigurations.getAwsQueueSpoutThreads());

        builder.setSpout("secondQueueSpout",
                new SqsQueueSpout(StormConfigurations.getQueueURL()
                        + StormConfigurations.getSecondQueueName(),
                        true), StormConfigurations.getAwsQueueSpoutThreads());

        builder.setBolt("transformerBolt", new TransformerBolt(),
                StormConfigurations.getTranformerBoltThreads())
                .shuffleGrouping("firstQueueSpout")
                .shuffleGrouping("secondQueueSpout");

        builder.setBolt("conversionBolt", new ConversionBolt(),
                StormConfigurations.getTranformerBoltThreads())
                .shuffleGrouping("transformerBolt");

        // To dispatch it to the corresponding bolts based on packet type
        builder.setBolt("dispatchBolt", new DispatcherBolt(),
                StormConfigurations.getDispatcherBoltThreads())
                .shuffleGrouping("conversionBolt");
```

Code snippet from SQSQueueSpout(extends BaseRichSpout):

```java
@Override
public void nextTuple() 
{
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = sqs.receiveMessage(
                    new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10));
            queue.addAll(receiveMessageResult.getMessages());
        }       
        Message message = queue.poll();
        if (message != null) 
        {
            try
            {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();           
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(message.getBody());
                //      ack(message.getReceiptHandle());
                if (reliable) {
                    collector.emit(getStreamId(message), new Values(jsonObj.toString()), message.getReceiptHandle());
                } else {
                    // Delete it right away
                    sqs.deleteMessageAsync(new DeleteMessageRequest(queueUrl, message.getReceiptHandle()));             
                    collector.emit(getStreamId(message), new Values(jsonObj.toString()));
                }
            }
            catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                LOG.error("SqsQueueSpout SQLException in SqsQueueSpout.nextTuple(): ", e);
            }
        } else {
            // Still empty, go to sleep.
            Utils.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
    }

    public String getStreamId(Message message) {
        return Utils.DEFAULT_STREAM_ID;
    }

    public int getSleepTime() {
        return sleepTime;
    }

    public void setSleepTime(int sleepTime) 
    {
        this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void ack(Object msgId) {
        System.out.println("......Inside ack in sqsQueueSpout..............."+msgId);
        // Only called in reliable mode.
        try {
            sqs.deleteMessageAsync(new DeleteMessageRequest(queueUrl, (String) msgId));
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) { }
    }

    @Override
    public void fail(Object msgId) {
        // Only called in reliable mode.
        try {
            sqs.changeMessageVisibilityAsync(
                    new ChangeMessageVisibilityRequest(queueUrl, (String) msgId, 0));
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) { }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        sqs.shutdown();
        ((AmazonSQSAsyncClient) sqs).getExecutorService().shutdownNow();
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("message"));
    }
```

Code snipped from my first Bolt(extends BaseRichBolt):

```java
public class TransformerBolt extends BaseRichBolt 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransformerBolt.class);
    private OutputCollector collector;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,
            OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        String eventStr = input.getString(0);
//some code here to convert the json string to map
//Map datamap, long packetId being sent to next bolt
    this.collector.emit(input, new Values(dataMap,packetId));       
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Exception while converting AWS SQS to HashMap :{}", e);
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("dataMap", "packetId"));
    }
}
```

Code snippet from second Bolt:

```java
public class ConversionBolt extends BaseRichBolt 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private OutputCollector collector;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,
            OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) 
    {
        try{
            Map dataMap = (Map)input.getValue(0);
            Long packetId = (Long)input.getValue(1);

                //this ack is not working
                this.collector.ack(input);
        }catch(Exception e){
            this.collector.fail(input);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    }
```

Kindly let me know if you need more information. Somebody shed some light on why the overridden ack in my spout is not getting called(from my second bolt)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `ack` all incoming tuples in **all** bolts, ie, add `collector.ack(input)` to `TransformerBolt.execute(Tuple input)`.

The log message you see is correct: your code calls `collector.ack(...)` and this call gets logged. A call to `ack` in your topology is **not** a call to `Spout.ack(...)`: Each time a Spout emits a tuple with a message ID, this ID gets registered by the running ackers of your topology. Those ackers will get a message on each ack of a Bolt, collect those and notify the Spout if all acks of a tuple got received. If a Spout receives this message from an acker, it calls it's own `ack(Object messageID)` method.

See here for more details: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html

Comment: Thanks Matthias. It works fine after acking each and every bolt. The moment I acked the first bolt the messages got deleted from 'messages available' section in SQS that made me thought what if i cudnt retrieve it back when it fails. Hence added ack only in the final bolt. My assumption was wrong. It works perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: The important point is to use the input tuple as an anchor in intermediate bolts (ie, none sink bolts) before acking it to tell Storm that the original input tuple is not (yet) fully processed -- only this step (ie, Bolt) completed processing.